# .change function is not working for Dates for even number of months in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have define this method

```
def change_date
    date = Date.today    
    start_date = date.change(year: 2015, month: (2 *  3)).at_beginning_of_quarter
    p 'aaaaaa'    
    p start_date
end
```

give me `invalid date` error .change is not working or am I doing it in a wrong way please guide me how to solve this. Thanx in advance.

Comment: @Pavan this is incorrect. `Date` also has the `change` method.

Comment: Yeah ur right its giving issues with even no of month but not with odd no but why its so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the month you are specifying doesn't have the current day.

I mean the current month (July) has 31 days but the month you're setting (June) has only 30 days. You can change your code like so:

```
# in Rails:
date = Date.today.beginning_of_month # or Date.today.change(day: 1)
```

Then chain your 'change' in front of the `date` variable.

Answer (score 2):

This actually happens, because today is the 31 of July, and not all months have 31 days in it, for example June, the 6th month, has only 30 days in it.